# How to do camera follow without drag and drop in Inspector in Unity?

Tags: unity, c#, camera

How to do camera following an object with special tag without drag and drop into Inspector? 
I have 2 prefab model they are not into hierarchy for the moment when player start play. To load selected model into scene I'm using the below code.

```
public GameObject[] players;
void Start () 
{
LoadPlayer ();
}
private void LoadPlayer()
{       
GameObject player =Instantiate(players[PlayerPrefs.GetInt(MyModel")]);
}
```

Because in other scene I can change my player model but I can't follow it using in c# script for camera
public Transform cause of I can't drop it in that place in Inspector. So in what way I can find current player object when game start to follow it by camera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give this script to player.this script find camera then give camera.position so you can use Lerp for following

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CameraFollow : MonoBehaviour {


    void Update () {
        Vector3 offest = new Vector3 (3,3,3);//Distance from object
        Vector3 cameraPos = Camera.main.transform.position;//position of camera
        Camera.main.transform.position= Vector3.Lerp (new Vector3(cameraPos.x,cameraPos.y,cameraPos.z), transform.position + offest, 0.8f *Time.deltaTime));
    }
}
```

If you want follow player just In one axis you can replace zero In upper code
for example if you want follow player In vector3.x you can do It easily:

```
Camera.main.transform.position= Vector3.Lerp (new Vector3(cameraPos.x,0,0), transform.position + offest, 0.1f);
```

Comment: But I have one more problem with that code, when I use that script my player object shakes when I move it. Is there any way to cut down that shakes?

Comment: if shakes mean camera smooth moving , you can remove Time.deltaTime from that code or you can don't use Lerp same this: Camera.main.transform.position = transform.position + offest;

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [GameObject.FindWithTag](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindWithTag.html) which will return the first active `GameObject` in the scene that matches the tag you pass in as the parameter. So assuming your player `GameObject` uses the tag `Player`, you would do the following.

```
void Start() {
    Transform player = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player").transform;
}
```

Comment: But to follow it by camera I mus use Transform from that object? Yes?

Answer (score 0):

In the player script, you could find the camera and make it follow the player with:

```
GameObject cam = GameObject.FindWithTag("Camera"); //assuming Camera has tag Camera
cam.transform.setParent(this.gameObject);
```

This makes the player the parent of the camera. This essentially does what the drag and drop does, but through code, so it works with prefabs.

Comment: If I add that code to player script it call me 
UnityEngine.GameObject' does not contain a definition for `setParent' and no extension method `setParent' of type `UnityEngine.GameObject' could be found

Comment: In child and parent you should use transform for example :   Camera.main.transform.parent = transform;           so you can fix your problem  >> Camera.main.transform.SetParent(gameObject.transform,true);

Comment: @MichałMasłoń oops, sorry. I didn't have unity open, so i assumed setParent was a method of the gameobject. I corrected my answer.